# PHP Session creates new Session ID for each script

Tags: php, session

I've looked pretty much everywhere and tried just about everything, but I can't seem to get these PHP sessions to work properly. Here is my setup:

I am running a ReactJS application locally that calls some PHP scripts (using axios) on a webserver to handle basic CRUD operations on a MySQL database. I am trying to utilize PHP sessions and I have no problem *creating* the session, but each time I call a script to either read or insert data, a new session ID gets generated and I lose my session variables.

I am including session_start() at the beginning of each script, and just refreshing the page alone generates a new session ID.

I've tried just about every value I could think of in the php.ini but nothing seems to be working.

```
session.auto_start  Off
session.cache_expire    1
session.cache_limiter   nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value
session.cookie_httponly no value
session.cookie_lifetime 14400
session.cookie_path /   
session.cookie_secure   no value
session.gc_divisor  1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  14400
session.gc_probability  1
session.lazy_write  On
session.name    PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value
session.save_handler    files
session.save_path   {hidden stuff}/var/php_sessions
session.serialize_handler   php
session.sid_bits_per_character  5
session.sid_length  32
session.upload_progress.cleanup On
session.upload_progress.enabled On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_
session.use_cookies 1
session.use_only_cookies    0
session.use_strict_mode 0
session.use_trans_sid   0
```

The sessions are definitely getting created properly and in the correct spot, but none of the sessions are actually resuming since new ones get created.

Comment: Added a simple session hit counter to the site and it works. Wondering if it's something with how react (axios) is calling the scripts. It might be creating a new "session" each time the PHP script gets called?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why but one possible solution would be to store the session in mysql in a table (you create yourself for that purpose).

Answer (score 0):

> session.save_path   {hidden stuff}/var/php_sessions

Make sure the user of the php process has write permission in this directory.

Comment: I do. As mentioned I can see the session file in the save path.